# What is the meaning of で in this sentence

Tags: particles, copula

I got very confused with the meaning of this sentence because of で. What does it mean here?

> オーストラリアは大陸で、それから国です。

Comment: Reference: [Conjugations of the Japanese Copula](http://www.japaneseprofessor.com/reference/grammar/conjugations-of-the-japanese-copula/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This 〜で is just connecting two です statements.  Your sentence is basically just contracting this

> オーストラリアは大陸です。そして、それから国です。　→　Australia is a continent.  It is also a country.

Comment: 「です」 does not conjugate to 「で」, I am afraid...

Answer (score 6):

It would be the conjunctive form of the auxiliary verb "だ" omitting the connecting  verb "有る" ( some suggest ある instead ), I think.

Now let's take at the [conjucating table of the auxiliary ”だ”.](https://www.kokugobunpou.com/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E-13-%E3%81%A0/)

As you can see at [image: the picture], だ in the conjunctive form is で and the suggested potential verb following after is 有り( あり ( which is also too the conjunctive form of the verb "有る",　or ある meaning "thus being, there being" etc etc, perhaps. ））

So, the very formal "original sentence" would be

> オーストリアは大陸で有り（ます）,( or あります ), それから国です。

But since phonetically speaking uttering "有り” is overloaded, I think it has become your

> オーストラリアは大陸で、それから国です。

---

Since I was asked why I use 有り、not 在り, I would like to [bring out an site](http://sptt-latin-subjunctive.blogspot.jp/2013/05/blog-post.html), which offers us a deep insight the difference between them.

From the site,

Regarding 有る、

> ２）＜そなわっていることが認められる（状態を保つ）＞は属性、所属、組成、性質、特徴、関係（所有を含む）に関連してくるが、高所から見れば１）の＜そなわっていること（もの）＞に特化された用法だ。つまりは、＜有る＞は＜モノ、コトにそなわっているの属性、組成、性質、特徴、関係（所有を含む）の存在を感じること＞をあらわす動詞ということになる。
>
> 試験がある
>
> 会議がある
>
> 事故があった
>
> などの＜ある＞＜あった＞の説明ができる。

The translation is

> 有る has the relationship with the meanings of its properties, belongings, compositions, characteristics, features, relationships ( including its possession ). In overall, the 有る makes its characterization in the former 1) "properties". 有る has the meaning of "feeling the existence" of properties, belongings, compositions, characteristics, features, relationships.
>
> There was an examination.
>
> There was a meeting.
>
> There was an accident.
>
> We can hereby use 有る of the above cases which means, "there be".

Whereas, the above site explains about 在る ( comparatively shortly )

> ＜在る＞は基本的に存在、所在でいいだろう。存在を示す＜在る＞は基本的な言葉だ。存在が先か認識が先かは哲学の問題だ。＜我思う、故に我あり＞。所在は場所を示す語で、＜XXに在る＞だ。

The translation is

> 在る would basically means its existence, "being there". 在る to mean its existence comes first. Should the existence come or the cognition come is the problem of its philosophy. --> "I think therefore I am". 所在｛しょざい｝ means its location such as "It is at XX."

The site summarizes as following.

> いずれにしても大和言葉＜あり＞は大きな動詞で、これに相当する動詞は英語（おそらく西洋語）にも中国語にもない。

The translation is

> Either way, Japanese Yamato Kotoba ＜あり＞ as a verb is so broad that the equivalent verb would not exist in any languages such as English even in Chinese.

**My conclusion**

Since Australia has the "property of being a landmass", I think here 有り would be OK.

---

Edited : even though [大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%9C%89%E3%82%8B-428392) lines up Kanjis, according to Shokolade san ( former chocolate san? ), from the comment line, "generally" ある is typed in Hiragana.

Thank you.

Have a good day.

Comment: I think ある is generally not written in kanji when it appears in the copular construction である.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11091/1478

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51737/discussion-on-answer-by-kentaro-tomono-the-meaning-of--in-this-sentence).

Answer (score 2):

Use で to connect nouns and なadjectives. Basically it's like "and".

For example:

彼女｛かのじょ｝は綺麗｛きれい｝でとても優しい｛やさしい｝です。