# Questions regarding で, に

Tags: grammar

> ロビーが満員**で**入室できませんでした
>
> 悩み事**で**眠れない

Does this で mean "because"? If so, can it be replaced by だから、なので and/or だということで?  (I think that で in the first sentence is supposed to be だ/です, but can it be translated as "because"?)

I think that に can also mean "because" at times, would it work this time?

> ロビーが満員**に**入室できませんでした
>
> 悩み事**に**眠れない

Regarding the second sentence, is the で used the same (だ/です)?

As you can see, I'm a bit confused with all these way of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`で` can be used to represent causal relationships in a similar way to *some* english uses of `because`, although I am hesitant to say that `で`=`because`. Your two uses of `に` do not really work; I would stay away from trying to use `に` as "because" in most cases.

Let's talk about `で` though. You've actually picked two very good examples, because although the `で` in each of them is representing a causal relationship, they do so in different ways.

> ロビーが満員で入室できませんでした

This `で` is an abbreviated `であり`. You can read more about this [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42454/what-is-the-meaning-of-%E3%81%A7-in-this-sentence?), but this is very close to an English `and`, and it can be used to represent causal relationships in a similar way.

> ロビーが満員であり、入室できませんでした
>
> The lobby was full (of people) and I could not get in.

No `because` necessary. Also note that `ロビー` is `lobby`, not `room`.

As for

> 悩み事で眠れない

This is the `で` particle we know and love. `悩み事` is the thing directly facilitating somebody not sleeping, in the way that the plane in `飛行機で行く` directly facilitates your traveling.

I think it's safe to translate this as "I could not sleep *because* of my worries", but I encourage you to think of this more as a natural extension of the way `で` is used than as it corresponding directly to `because`.

Edit: It might be best to think of `because of`, rather than just `because`, as the possible translation for `で` here. It really only plays this role with nouns, which in English will end up as `because of [noun]`.

Comment: Thank you! Why doesn't に work as "because" in most cases? I often see it in novels, so I'm wondering.

Comment: @Ushiromiya can you give me an example sentence where に is used as "because"? It would help me get a better feel for what you're asking.

Comment: Hmm.. I think I've been told this one is used as a kind of "because": "お土産を気に入ってくれたことに安堵すると." I don't have any other sentence at the moment. In jisho, it is said that に can be used for "4. because of (reason)"

Comment: I was wondering if this was going to come back to ことに. I would translate the sentence you gave as "I'm relieved that you liked the souvenir". You could translate this as "I am relieved because you liked the souvenir" if you really wanted to, but I think "that" is more applicable to "ことに", and in any case に only shows up here because  the verb (安堵する) takes に. It's definitely not a generalizeable "because".

Comment: 「に」の後には感情を表す語句が来るのかも。。。「映画**に**感動する」「知らせ**に**驚く」「借金**に**悩む」「返済**に**苦しむ」「～くれたこと**に**安堵する・安心する」「～されたこと**に**がっかりする・失望する・怒る」とか・・・「眠れない」って感情じゃないから「悩み事**に**眠れない」って変なのかも・・

Comment: Then, is it more of a "because of/by" than just a "because"? For instance, "I've been moved by the movie" and "I've been moved because of the movie" seems fine to me. However, even if we could say "I can't sleep because of X" we couldn't say "I can't sleep by X" (for explaining a reason). Therefore, it would rule out the possibility of using に in this sentence.

Comment: It's often difficult to produce perfect 1:1 mappings of English and Japanese words; I think that に in these cases is closer to "by", but I also think @Schokolade's comment really hit the nail on the head - it's used primarily to represent feeling some way about something. I personally look at it more as you feeling an emotion toward that thing  (and in that sense being directional like other uses of に), but it does end up as "by" in English and could sometimes be translated as "because". "I've been moved because of the movie" is a little strange though.